# Tap area ridiculously small for UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton that I created like this:

```
let closeButton = UIButton(type: .System)
closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 92, g: 92, b: 118, alpha: 1)
closeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "closeCross")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
closeButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
closeButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10)

closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "close", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(messageView.frame.maxX - 30, 0, 20, 20)
closeButton.center.y = messageView.bounds.midY
```

The problem is that the tap is triggered only if you are a pixel away from the center of the `UIButton`. The image I set is a png that is a cross `X`.

Even if I tap on the cross (but not exactly on the middle, thanks the simulator the precision), it doesn't work.

I don't understand. The background isn't clear. Whether or not I change the content/image edge insets doesn't change a thing. Whether or not I use an image rendering mode doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Did you try to set a frame for the button manually? Or change the button type?

Comment: What does closeButton.frame print out?

Comment: Just updated the post with the frame

Comment: It prints out `(x : 345, y : 10, width : 20, height : 20)`

Answer (score 7):

Its best practice to keep UIbuttons at least 44x44 in size.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

> Make it easy for people to interact with content and controls by giving each interactive element ample spacing. Give tappable controls a hit target of about 44 x 44 points.

So I would set your frame to be bigger then 20pts, also what size is your image 20pts? Could it be clipping outside of the button, check that clipToBounds is set to yes.

There also a more radical approach, and that's to create a subclass of UIButton with a touch area of at least 44.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGFloat widthDelta = 44.0 - self.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat heightDelta = 44.0 - self.bounds.size.width;
    CGRect largerBounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -0.5 * widthDelta, -0.5 * heightDelta);
    return CGRectContainsPoint(largerBounds, point);
}
```

Another thing to do is investigate the button using reveal( http://revealapp.com/)

Comment: You won't need reveal, its included on the new XCode versions. Try the button right besides the debugger panel: http://imgur.com/0KVy8nR

Comment: By about Xcode 12 they might have finished the feature! =P I find it's no where near as useful as reveal but that's my personal opinion. It also worth noting you must pay for reveal.

Answer (score 2):

Here is actually how I fixed it:

```
closeButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(noConnectionMessageView.frame.maxX - 40, 0, 40, 40)
```

Comment: beat me to it. The negative insets meant that the image actually looked larger than the target area.

Answer (score 2):

It only happens when there is no title along with image on UIButton. If you don't want to add a title, there is a hack...

Just add a space as title text. Whole area of your button would start responding.

It miraculously worked for me.